# ffmpeg rtmp server connection issues

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, rtmp

1. I am trying to stream using ffmpeg rtmp using,

   ffmpeg -i out2.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a aac -listen 1 -ar 44100 -ab 64000 -f flv rtmp://localhost/live

The process starts but nothing is happening after handler_name[image]

2. When I use the command, ffmpeg -f flv -i out2.mp4 -c copy -f flv -listen 1 rtmp://localhost:1935/live/app.

I get---> Cannot open connection tcp://localhost:1935?listen&listen_timeout=-1000
rtmp://localhost/live: Immediate exit requested

Answer (score 1):

I followed your instructions. I changed localhost to 127.0.0.1:10000, and I was using input from an rtsp.

Here is my command. It worked for me. I was able to get the stream in VLC player.

```
ffmpeg -i "rtsp://someurl/" -c:v copy -c:a aac -listen 1 -ar 44100 -ab 64000 \
       -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:10000/live
```